# android - index for ListView?

Tags: android, design-patterns

Is it possible to have an index on the righthand side of a ListView?  This is possible on the iPhone where running down the righthand side the alphabet is shown.  Touching a letter on the alphabet brings one to the beginning of the items in the ListView that start with that letter.

Is there built-in code in Android for this functionality?  Or is this something one would have to custom make?

Comment: I don't really have an answer, other than that yes, you would have to build this custom, but I definitely think that would be a nice thing to have as built-in functionality. Better yet, something like the Zune HD's interface for going through long lists of music (if you haven't seen it, look it up on YouTube, it's very nice). Basically at the beginning of a section you have the letter for that section; tap that, and a grid of the index appears, and you press one to jump to it. Might be a fun project for me to try... :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is no exactly what you want. There is a very similar thing. First set fast scroll mode of your ListView:

```
ListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
```

next implement the following Interface by your adapter:

```
android.widget.SectionIndexer
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SectionIndexer.html

This way you will be able to scroll fast your ListView with a thumb button.

If you implement SectionIndexer correctly you will be able to see a alphabet letter on which you are currently on during fast scrolling.

Comment: Great answer. This is also "the Android way" so it should be preferred to trying to make it work like the iPhone.

Answer (score 5):

Check this one http://hello-android.blogspot.com/2010/11/sideindex-for-android.html .. exactly the same..